# Console.log is clearing out immediately and I don't know why

Tags: html, console.log

I am trying to test this small feature and I believe I wrote everything correctly, however it does not show up in my console.log. Is there something I am over looking?

```js
          var inputChange = function() {
           var inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
            console.log(inputVal)
          };
```

```css
 form{
                width: 300px;
                height: 75px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                margin: auto;
            }
```

```html
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    
    <form>
      <input id="input" type="text" name = "input" placeholder="Type Something"/>
      <input type="submit" onclick ="inputChange()"/>
    </form>
    
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are missing the start html and head tags

Comment: I didn't include it in the code here but I have it in my code

Comment: Which browser are we talking of ?

Answer (score 13):

HTML `inputs` of type `submit` send their form whenever you click on them, so the script is getting called, and you're seeing the output briefly, but then the page is getting reloaded and the console is getting cleared. Change

```
<input type="submit" onclick ="inputChange()"/>
```

to

```
<input type="button" onclick ="inputChange()"/>
```

and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks, this change worked. How odd. I had gotten that but the type as submit due to a reference that had it like that and it worked. Ill have to look deeper into that and see why it worked for them and not for me. Very helpful!

Comment: Or add `return false`, preferably in a proper event listener.

Comment: With Chrome and "Preserve log" enabled I was able to see the message. Adding something like "value of inputVal" in front of the value helps because otherwise you might print an empty line depending on what the user entered.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because your form is submitting to itself and the page loads in a fraction of seconds for you to notice the difference.

There is 2 way you can solve this in your case.

**One:**
Add `onsubmit="return false;"` attribute in your form element.

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <input id="input" type="text" name = "input" placeholder="Type Something"/>
  <input type="submit" onclick ="inputChange()"/>
</form>
```

Here is the Snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/ppn5ngwh/1/

**Two:**
Modify your javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].onsubmit = function() {return false;}
var inputChange = function() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("input").html;
    console.log(inputVal)
};
```

Here is the snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/ppn5ngwh/